# How to set the default selected value while clicking on submit or very first time while loading - React Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

This is my category state

```
const [category, setCategory] = useState('');
```

This's the form element:

```
 <select onChange={e => setCategory(e.target.value)}>
                                        <Options options={categoryList} value={category}/>
                                        </select>
```

On changing the value, i'm getting category as selected

```
const handleBusinessInfoSubmit = (e) => {
        try{
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log("category selected is " +category);

        }
        catch{
            console.log("something went wrong!");
        }
    }
```

**How do I setCategory state when the user doesn't change the value and hits Submit?**

For reference sake, here is category list that will come as dynamic later in key value pair

```
 const categoryList = [
        {
            id: 1,
            value: 'Public Services'
        }, {
            id: 2,
            value: 'Automotive'
        }
        ];
// generate select dropdown option list dynamically
function Options({ options }) {
    return (
        options.map(option => 
                    <option key={option.id} value={option.value}>                                   
                    {option.value}
                    </option>)
                   );
        }
```

Comment: It will not be better to wait for category list to come and then at hook `useState(categoryList[0])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably I would add default initial value to `useState` as instead of `''`:

```
const [category, setCategory] = useState(categoryList[0]);
```

Or maybe if the data is coming dynamically then calling `setCategory()` with the value from the API result what you would like to have as default.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks!!
categoryList[0].value this helped :)